# I am using shelvedb in docker. but when i am writing or updating my DB it's now happening

Tags: docker, dockerfile, python-3.10, shelve

ShelveDB is not updating in the docker.
I am using multiple thread in my code and also i am not closing my shelveDB because of i can't close DB. I have to update my DB after every 5 second.
i am creading docker file on latest ubuntu and python in 3.10

i tried to use sync() method also but it's not happning.

Comment: I am using shelvedb in docker. but when i am writing or updating my DB it's not happening